# coldfusion: display form value using variable

Tags: forms, coldfusion

Coming from a form page, I have the following value: test1, test2, test3 .. test50.

To display 1 of them, I can do this

```
<output> #form.test1# </output>
```

But I want to display all of them using a loop, how would I do it?

```
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#form.build_found#" >
    <output> #form.testi# </output>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Yes, accessing dynamically named variables is common task. Here's one thread (short answer: most everything is a scope. use structure notation `scopeName["dynamicVariableName"]` [Getting values from CFLOOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144133/getting-values-from-cfloop)

Comment: Here is some light reading for you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683868/display-cfloop-items-in-order-from-form/19684136

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work:

```html
<cfoutput>
   <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#form.build_found#" >
        #form["test" & i ]# 
   </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

A few cfml coders might tend to use the `evaluate()` function. Don't use it, because it opens security holes in code like that.